# What is correct iOS notification payload format

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS client which talks to a java server which also handles an android client.
Since android client is pre-built, the notifications that are received are of the generic xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <serverAppresponse type="com.server.data.AppResponse" packetId="">
   <atom key="key1">true</atom>
   <atom key="userFirstName">ABC</atom>   
   <atom key="userLastName">PQR</atom>
</serverAppresponse>
```

Is such a format acceptable?

Or the format in [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW15) is mandatory?

Comment: On this link there is nothing said about XML, so you should use JSON for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a push notification to the iOS client, you need to use the payload format required by the Apple Push Notification Service (the one in the link you provided, in JSON). If you want to send a push notification **to the Android client**, *from the iOS client*, you'll need to use whichever format the Android service (such as C2DM) requires. Basically, you use the format of the service which is going to send data to the *recipient* of the push notification.